# Which color in emission spectrum do we really see?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photon-emission, electrochemistry

For example, potassium has this emission spectrum according to google image
[image]

It is typical (and kinda necessary) for atoms to have multiple emission lines, so what determines which color we actually see when we burn the thing?
For example, why do we only see lilac flame when we light up potassium? Is it just a mixed color of different emission lines? Or is there a dominant emission frequency? If so, does that mean using flames at different temperatures (which will provide different energy/ photons) will give us different dominant emission color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to mix. Atoms do have multiple emission lines and the color you see is what your eye interprets from combining all of them individually. This is different than physically combining color to create new colors. In that case the atoms are different and emit different emission lines. See this https://youtu.be/C9aaPOBUi1w